# Is "help (to) do sth for sb" right?

Tags: phrases, phrasal-verbs, learning

I am a English learner. When I had English class, my teacher told me a phrase.

> help (to) do sth for sb

I felt very confused about this phrase. Because there is a verb that has a verb phrase as an object. I learned "help sb (to) do sth". Which phrase is right or they are both right? If they are both right, what is the differences between these two phrases?
As a elementary English learner, there may be some wrong in my article. Please forgive me.

Comment: Are you a Chinese speaker? I wish the Chinese speakers (as used to be the case years ago) would use a anglicized Chinese name instead of using a name in English. Those names are usually prettier and there was a long tradition of it. [I felt very confused about etc.]

Answer (score 2):

**help (to) do sth for sb**

> I helped to get the house ready for Aunt Mary.

It doesn't specify *who* I helped - whoever was in charge of the job that I helped with.

**help sb (to) do sth**

> I helped my mother to clean the house.

Answer (score 0):

> help (to) do sth for sb

In this phrase "for sb" is linked with the second verb, not "help."

You can say: "I helped open the door for the child" because you can say: "I opened the door for the child."  The use of "for" is not grammatically related to the use of "help."  It simply means "for the benefit of sb."

You can also say: "I helped the child (to) open the door" or "I helped the child (to) go inside."  But you usually cannot express the same meaning by saying: "*I helped go inside for the child" because here "for" means only "for the child's benefit."

When you say: "I helped the child (to) open the door," you mean that you enabled the child to open the door.  The two of you acted together.  If you say: "I helped (to) open the door for the child," you mean that you joined with other unnamed people in the situation to open the door for the child's benefit but say nothing about the child's actions.  The child could even have been carried unconscious in someone's arms.

Comment: so you think they are both rational? which one is more commonly used?

Comment: @Zhang I completely reedited by answer, since I had misread your question.